# How to convert multi string as the values of one array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have multi string with the names:

```
$string[0], $string[1], ..., $string[$i]
```

I want to convert them to one array like:

```
array($string[0], $string[1], ..., $string[$i])
```

For example, if there are 4 strings, the array is:

```
array($string[0], $string[1], $string[2], $string[3])
```

Comment: In what language? php? Please add an appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: ehm... isn't your variable `$string` the result you want?

Comment: `$arrayOfStrings = array($string[0], $string[1], $string[2], $string[3]);`
??

Answer (score 1):

> array($string[0], $string[1], $string[2], $string[3])

Doing this is exactly doing nothing. $sting is itself an array having values $string[0], $string[1],.....$string[$i]

Comment: Oh, so that's how it is. Sorry for being an "amateur". Thanks for showing me this.

Answer (score 0):

Say if ur input is:

```
      $input = "test1, test2, test3, test4";
```

You could do,

```
      $to_array = implode(",", $input);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No. For example, we have a textarea tag to input text. Then the info will be converted by some function, eventually resulting in these separated strings through loop: $string[0], $string[1], ..., $string[$i]